# Can I install a printer server to solve printer out of memory problem (by split into one-page jobs)?

Tags: drivers, server, printing

First of all, my printer suffers the out of memory problem, when printing some long document.  This is due to manufacturer's cost-down strategy (and my budget, of course).

Is it possible to install a Linux (Ubuntu perhaps) printer server, and a proper driver which divides all kinds of printing jobs into many one-page jobs, so that the printer won't get out-of-memory problem?

Comment: I don't know any ready-made solution but I think it could be done using [TEA4Cups](https://wiki.debian.org/Tea4CUPS) and some shell scripting.

Comment: Any way to cheaply upgrade the memory on the printer? What kind of documents are you printing when it chokes?

Comment: I am printing PDF file.